# Choosing SQL join types for Entity Framework 4

Tags: sql-server, performance, join, entity-framework-4, sql-view

I have a query for example:

```
var personList = context.People;
```

People is a view that has 2 joins on it and about 2500 rows and takes ~10 seconds to execute.
Looking at the Estimated Execution plan tells me that it is using a nested loop.

Now if i do this:

```
var personList = context.People.Where(r => r.Surname.Length > -1);
```

Execution time is under a second and the execution plan is using a Hash Join.

Adding "OPTION (HASH JOIN)" to the generated SQL has the desired effect of increasing performance.

So my question is ...

How can i get the query to use a Hash Join? It can't be added to the view (I tried, it errors).
Is there an option in EF4 that will force this? Or will i have to put it in a stored procedure?

---

### RE: View

```
SELECT     dbo.DecisionResults.ID, dbo.DecisionResults.UserID, dbo.DecisionResults.HasAgreed, dbo.DecisionResults.Comment, 
                      dbo.DecisionResults.DateResponded, Person_1.Forename, Person_1.Surname, Site_1.Name, ISNULL(dbo.DecisionResults.StaffID, - 999) 
                      AS StaffID
FROM         dbo.DecisionResults INNER JOIN
                      Server2.DB2.dbo.Person AS Person_1 ON Person_1.StaffID = dbo.DecisionResults.StaffID INNER JOIN
                      Server2.DB2.dbo.Site AS Site_1 ON Person_1.SiteID = Site_1.SiteID
ORDER BY Person_1.Surname
```

If i add OPTION(HASH JOIN) to the end it will error with :

> 'Query hints' cannot be used in this query type.

But running that script as a query works fine.

Comment: hash join should work in the view. can you paste the code that errors?